# How to create native popup menu to copy some layout content into clipboard

Tags: nativescript

Could anyone suggest me some sample application or code snippets on how to implement such popup menu for iOS and Android?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, use a `TextField` instead of `Label` and disable editing on it. Then by default you will get the copy menu.

For Android, you cloud use the [nativescript-popup](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-popup) plugin to show similar popup and use [nativescript-clipboard](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-clipboard) plugin to copy text.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-popup
tns plugin add nativescript-clipboard
```

Comment: Yes, it is the possible solution, but unfortunately, such popup is not native for iOS. So it seems that to implement this functionality we need to dive in native calls separate for iOS and Android (which is not so trivial ☹️).

Comment: As I mentioned already in the answer, use popup only for Android. Use non editable Text Field for iOS to get the native popup. Yes, of course you will have to do it separately for iOS and Android, when you have a specific UI requirement on respective platforms. May be you can write a custom component that could be reused though out your app.